# How do create a view excluding the data that does not match any of the conditions set in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-view

I'm trying to create a separate view that takes data from another view and adds one column for classification purposes; however, as it is now, I have an awful lot of records that have a NULL value under that additional column... I was wondering if I can manage somehow to exclude the records that do not comply with any of the conditions set in the CASE statement I use to alter the view? Thanks in advance

```
alter view2
select col1, case when col2='love' then 'non-shop'
when col2='choose' and col3='brand' then 'non-shop'
when col2='choose' and col3<>'brand' then 'shop'
when col2='buy' then 'shop'
end traffic_type
from view1
```

Comment: `CASE` expression*

Comment: A view is basically just saved select statement so you can edit your where clause to just not show those rows. I would just put that query above in a CTE and then say "where CTE.NewColumn is not null"

Comment: On a different note, I would recommend against a nested view. These have a tendency to perform poorly. Bring the DDL from your other view into this view, don't nest them.

Comment: To expand on @Larnu's point about nested views. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off my comment:

```
ALTER VIEW view2 as 

;WITH CTE AS
(
select col1, case when col2='love' then 'non-shop'
when col2='choose' and col3='brand' then 'non-shop'
when col2='choose' and col3<>'brand' then 'shop'
when col2='buy' then 'shop'
end as traffic_type
from view1
)
select * from CTE
where traffic_type is not null
```

As @Larnu said I would just put the orignal query in here, not chain off of view1

Comment: T-SQL requires the object type in a DDL statement. For example `CREATE TABLE` `ALTER FUNCTION`, `DROP PROC`, etc *(Also, `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginnator")*

Comment: Yes sorry, was just copying the alter from op. And yes the semi-colon normally should come AFTER any statements, not before (in fact the above it's not even needed) - just force of habit for me with CTE's for simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not saying that this is "wrong", but the fact the the OP has marked this as the solution without comment suggests they've ignored the comments the performance concerns... As they say, "You can lead a Horse to water..."

Comment: mmm - nothing to say that he can't take the solution and work in the original query in place of the view1 though *shrugs*.  Hopefully he does that...

Answer (score 1):

I would do :

```
alter view view2 as
    select col1, v11.traffic_type
    from view1 v1 cross apply
         ( values (case when (col2 = 'love') or (col2 = 'choose' and col3 = 'brand')
                        then 'non-shop'
                        when (col2 = 'choose' and col3 <> 'brand') or (col2 = 'buy')
                        then 'shop'
                   end)
         ) v11(traffic_type)
    where v11.traffic_type is not null;
```